# django, rails, PHP with GWT

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, django, gwt

I am doing a comparative study of Django vs Rails vs PHP as backend using GWT as front end GUI. The backend is connected to a network of devices. The main features of GUI would be (1) forms to view, edit, delete data in tables. (2) Upload and download files. (3) Monitor display(s) to show the state of devices in network.

1. Is there an existing open source project that uses GWT frontend with Django backend? How about GWT + rails and GWT + PHP?
2. Any recommendations on what would fit in best in this scenario?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should google around..
2. I'd recommend using Java and GWT-RPC as the backend, because:

   a. You'd be using same language on backend and frontend.

   b. You'd be using (sharing) same domain model classes between backend and frontend.

   c. GWT-RPC is type-safe.

   d. With GWT-RPC you would not need to do JSON to objects mapping.

Comment: I'd rather recommend RequestFactory than GWT-RPC.

Comment: Some time ago (cca 6 months) I checked out RequestFactory, but it could not transfer Maps - which I needed for my project. Is this still the case?

Comment: Unfortunately yes (though it'll change: `AutoBean`, which backs RF, supports maps for a few weeks). I'm sending lists of entries instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your best experience would be by using java on the server side. I tried using GWT with php and rails, although it is totally doable, I found that the smoother experience is by using java servlets on the backend.